# Items of std::array are changed unintentionally out of context

Tags: c++, reference, stl

I'm trying passing the reference of array to class object by constructor, and operating the items in that object.
But, I'm afraid that these items in array are changed just after reaching at the beginning of MySort::sort() below. (not changed before entering MySort::sort())

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct MySort
{
    T &_n;
    size_t _s;

public:
    MySort(T n) : _n(n)
    {
        _s = _n.size();
    }

    void sort()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _s - 1; i++)
        {
            for (size_t j = i + 1; j < _s; j++)
            {
                if (_n[i] > _n[j])
                    std::swap(_n[i], _n[j]);
            }
        }
        cout << "teste" << endl;
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &ost, const MySort &c)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < c._s; i++)
            ost << c._n[i];
        return ost;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    array<int, 5> numbers{2, 5, 1, 7, 3};

    MySort<array<int, 5>> bubble{numbers};
    bubble.sort();
    cout << bubble << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

- In the case of passing array by copy, It works correctly.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor

```
MySort(T n) : _n(n)
{
    _s = _n.size();
}
```

Here you set `_n` to reference a input object which will get destroyed upon leaving the constructor. This is plain UB.

To fix it write

```
MySort(T& n) : _n(n)
{
    _s = _n.size();
}
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot. The example to fix was so helpful for me!

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor `MySort(T n)`,  you are making a copy of the array,  then storing a reference to the copy,  but then the copy goes out of scope,  so you have a dangling reference.

If you want to use a reference,  you should pass a reference to the original object,  `MySort(T &n)`, and make sure that the original object is always in scope during the lifetime of the MySort object.